# Do I ever need to `await` tasks for in a visitor pattern?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visitor-pattern

For example, consider:

```
public class Student
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        while (true)
        {

            await ReadBook();
            await Task.Delay(rand.Next(4000));
        }
    }

    public async Task ReadBook()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Main
{
    async Task Run()
    {
        var s1 = new Student();
        var s2 = new Student();

        s1.Run();
        s2.Run();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Books read: {0}", GetReadBooks());
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
    }

    int GetReadBooks()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Do I need to await `Student.Run()`, or even maintain a reference to the returned task at all?  I understand the need if I ever want to cancel the task; I suspect I also need to await this in order to receive any exceptions thrown by `Student.Run()`, but beyond that, do I care about these tasks?

Comment: You must never let your exceptions go unobserved. That, the exception handling, should be reason enough to stay with `await` even without any other reasons.

Comment: Consider it more of an academic question; I expect to eventually use await for the exceptions as well.

Comment: There is no visitor pattern in this question. Please, change the title and remove the tag.

Comment: `await` won't make the `async` task to run asynchronously, it will hold the main thread at that point and wait for that task to get completed. So, even if you add `await` for both `Run()` calls, it is still a synchronous operation.

Comment: That is in large part my question; is there any benefit *to* awaiting these?  I understand that awaiting them inline will cause them to run synchronously.

Comment: If you want to run them synchronously, then there is no point of adding await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can two students read books at the same time?

Leaving out the `await` would mean `s2.Run()` starts when `s1.Run()` is in progress. In this case, you *want* `s1.Run()` and `s2.Run()` to run concurrently, so you definitely should not simply write `await s1.Run();`. Since your loops are never-ending, awaiting them doesn't make too much sense except for exceptions, but I would be surprised if your loops are truly never-ending in your real code. `Task` is intended to represent something that finishes at some point. And if you can tell when that finishes, then you can determine based on that what the appropriate place to `await` the task is.

I would probably guess that saving the tasks in variables, and putting `await Task.WhenAll(run1, run2);` somewhere after, would be the most appropriate, but depending on your real code, it might not be suitable for you.

Comment: There *is* an await inside `Student.Run()` when calling `ReadBook()`. The missing await is when calling `Student.Run()`.  No, a student can't read 2 books as the same time, but 2 students *can* read the same book at the same time.

Comment: That is not how `await` will work right? By the time the flow hits `await`, it will wait for that line of code to execute completely. So the above code is executing synchronous

Comment: @Rollie Ah sorry, misread that part. The point I tried to make still applies, but there's more to it for `Run()`, edited to address that.

Comment: With your updates, that's actually what I am doing (with a bit of LINQ syntactic sugar);  this may be all there is to the answer, basically "nope, nothing more to be gained by awaiting beyond exceptions".